# Castle.Windsor IoC-container specific configuration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have chosen Castle.Windsor as IoC container for my app. This is my first IoC expirience so I need an advice configuring it.

The root class of the app is `Scheduler`. It plans and performs different kinds of "jobs". Each job implements `IWorker` interface, so I decided to inject a `List<IWorker>` into `Scheduler`. There will be many kind of "jobs" later, now there are two: `Cleaner` and `Writer`. `Scheduler` needs single instance of `Cleaner`, so default Singleton Lifestyle is OK. But I also need to inject number of `Writer`s depends on count of XML files in some folder. What is optimal pattern to achieve this in my case?

Configuring container:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
// For IList injecting
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ListResolver(container.Kernel, true));
// Registering Scheduler
container.Register(CastleRegistration.Component.For<IScheduler>().ImplementedBy<Scheduler>);
// Registering Workers
container.Register(CastleRegistration.Component.For<IWorker>().ImplementedBy<Writer>());
container.Register(CastleRegistration.Component.For<IWorker>().ImplementedBy<Writer>());
// ... there are multiple Writers depends on XML files count
container.Register(CastleRegistration.Component.For<IWorker>().ImplementedBy<Cleaner>());
// Resolving
var sched = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
```

Scheduler:

```
public class Scheduler : IScheduler
{
    public IList<IWorker> Workers { get; set; }

    public Scheduler(IList<IWorker> workers)
    {
        Workers = workers;
    }
}
```

Writer:

```
public class Writer : IWorker
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public Writer()
    {
    }

    public Writer(string source)
    {
        Source = source;
    }
}
```

Cleaner:

```
public class Cleaner : IWorker
{
    public Cleaner()
    {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I need to pass a parameter object (deserialized from XML) in each of `Parser`s.
Should I just use `foreach` loop in container configuration? Can Windsor's Typed factory help here? I need some guideline.

Comment: I don't actually see a problem. What isn't working?

Comment: sounds like you actually want a WriterFactory to be injected and then create the writers as you need them for the files in your directory

Comment: Sam, could you please give more complex answer with couple lines of code?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the purpose of the container! - You do not inject instances - you register them and then get an instance of them by asking the container. I can see this by the double registration of Writer class. You must not push different instances into the IoC. You have to register them with the proper lifestyle and then ask IoC to resolve them for you.

Comment: @Ognyan, I understand what you say and I understand container purpose. Just can't properly put in words my problem. I know, that same lines with Writer registration are now wright. With that lines I wanted to show that I want to register N Writers there for each XML file, and pass object deserialized from that XML as parameter to its Writer. XML is a source information for Writer class.

Comment: In this case you need WriterFactory as @SamHolder stated. Inside the factory you can store the N writers. If you register Writer just like you did you are registering it with Singleton lifestyle and Castle will bring you the first registration every time you request it.

Comment: @ValeO added an answer with some more details. you need to use the `@SamHolder` for me to get a notification, so didn't see this until the previous comment was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically what you want to do is something along these lines:

```
public class WriterFactory : IWriterFactory
{
    public Writer Create(string fileName)
    {
        return new Writer(fileName);
        //if your writers have other dependencies then inject those into the factory via the constructor and use them here
    }
}
```

then register this factory

```
container.Register(CastleRegistration.Component.For<IWriterFactory>().ImplementedBy<WriterFactory>());
```

Then anywhere you need to create a writer take a dependency on the `IWriterFactory` in the constructor

Comment: OK, I got it. Are there any differencies between your factory registration and this line: `container.Register(Component.For<IWriterFactory>().AsFactory());` ? (it's from Castle documentation). Am I right if I say that I mostly must try to avoid factories? Better solution is when container "builds" whole objects graph if I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm not over familiar with Castles particular IOC container so I'm not sure if you should use this method or not. You shouldn't avoid factories, you need them when the objects created rely of dynamic data which is provided at run time (like the list of files in this case).

Comment: @ValeO I think your approach is better. Always try to create instances by the container. I don't know it will help, but I solve similar problmes like this:
http://uhaciogullari.github.io/blog/2014/01/05/strategy-pattern-with-dependency-injection/

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları your payment method resolver is just a factory for producing payment methods... and the approach doesn't work here because you can't know in advance what files exist in the directory. and that might change during run time as new files are added